# How to build Makefile project for Android?

Tags: android, gcc, makefile, android-ndk, android.mk

I want to use GPL software on Android. And I installed Android NDK.
NDK Document explains Makefile Project, but it's used .configure file.
Unfortunately my favorite Apery has not .configure file, so I can't build.
How should I do to build this type project?

[github](https://github.com/HiraokaTakuya/apery/blob/master/src/Makefile)